# Laravel 5.5: 'Collator' not found with PHP 7.1.19 installed

Tags: php, laravel

The question explains it all.. I get this exception when running code:

```
$collator = new \Collator(App::getLocale());
```

error:

```
Class 'Collator' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Collator' not found at /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/VendorEvent.php:88)
```

Comment: What is `Collator`? Is it a class you created? If so, where is it located and can you show its code?

Comment: @Jerodev [Collator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php)

Comment: Do you have the `intl` PHP module installed? A simple `php -m` will show the list of installed modules. I'm guessing `intl` is not part of that list.

Comment: Are you sure the line you provided is where the error occurs? It seems like you forgot an `\\` somewhere.

Comment: @Bogdan no not installed

Comment: @belgiums Then you just need to install it. Because the `Collator` class is part of the module, as you can see from the [intl docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

Comment: Down-vote for the answer and self-action containing question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by installing the `php-intl` extension. This class exists in intl extensions

Run the following commad and restart you web server.

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

hope this helps

Comment: i'm running on OS Mojave, apt-get is not possible, though?

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS

```
sudo yum install php-intl
```